# copy & paste menu of UITextField is missing some time

Tags: iphone, ios4

In my app, sometimes all the textfield 's copy&paste menu is missing when the user is tapping in the textfield.
But when the user kill the app and restart again, the function comes back.

Has anyone encountered this problem before?
I do not subclass UITextField, what could cause such problem?
Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that in on of my view controller, I used two alertViews. After the first alertView diss, I immediately pop up the second UIAlertView in the callback

```
- (void) alertView:(UIAlertView *) alertView clickedButtonAtIndexL(NSInteger) buttonIndex
{
//[thesecondalertview show];
}
```

Since the firstAlert view does not completely dimiss, pop up the second alertview it may cause the UIWindow disorder.
    If we pop up the second UIAlertView in the first alertviews's callback,

```
- (void) alertview:(UIAlertView*)alertview didDissmissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger) buttonIndex
```

the problem solved.